# Access sum top 5 for group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access table in which I want to sum top 5 results for each group.
Table example:

```
 Club Points    Score   
  c1    25     200 
  c1    20    150 
  c1    15    100 
  c1    25    200 
  c1    25    200 
  c1    25    200 
  c2    25    200 
  c2    20    150 
  c2    15    100
```

Desired result would be:

```
Club    Points    Score   
c1      120       950
c2      60        450
```

I hope someone can help me because I cannot find right query for this

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(Points),SUM(Score) FROM table_name GROUP BY Club
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this correctly, you really need a unique id for each row.  The basic idea is:

```
select club, sum(points), sum(score), count(*) as nummatches
from t
where score in (select top 5 t2.score
                from t as t2
                where t2.club = t.club
                order by t2.score desc
               ) 
group by club;
```

The problem is that `TOP` in MS Access really does `TOP WITH TIES`.  So, if there are ties, you can get more than five values.  That is why the query includes the number of matches.

To fix this, you can do:

```
select club, sum(points), sum(score), count(*) as nummatches
from t
where score in (select top 5 t2.score
                from t as t2
                where t2.club = t.club
                order by t2.score desc, id  -- the `id` makes each row unique
               ) 
group by club;
```

Comment: It seems that this is more problematic. I have tried your solution but I received an error that it cannot find t.club. The problem is that table t is a query which is created from crosstab query. So I had to add parameters to this new query one was t.club=short text and id=integer. But now when I start query it demands that I put in t.club value and id value. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: `t.club` is a reference to the outer query.  This is definitely something that MS Access supports.